# Angular $resource cache not working

Tags: node.js, angularjs, caching

I would like to cache resources in my MEAN-stack application.

In the client I use a service that calls the server, where I put a trace to see if the cache is working (and I see this trace everytime I reload the page).

In this example I retrieve a list of cities.

My controler:

```
angular.module('mean.cars').controller('CarsController', ['$scope', '$http', '$stateParams', '$location', 'Global','Cities',
    function ($scope, $http, $stateParams, $location, Global, Cities) {

$scope.cities = Cities.query();
```

My service:

```
angular.module('mean.sol').factory('Cities', ['$resource',  function($resource) {return $resource('cities/', {}, {list : {method : 'GET', cache : true } });}]);
```

I also tried with these solutions:

```
mod.factory('Cities', ['$resource',  function($resource, $cacheFactory) {return $resource('cities/', {}, {list : {
        'get': { method:'GET', cache: $cacheFactory },
    'query': { method:'GET', cache: $cacheFactory, isArray:true } } });}]);
```

Or:

```
mod.factory('Cities', function($resource){
return $resource('cities/', {},
    {get: 
        {
            cache: true,
            method: 'GET'
        }
    }
);
```

})

All is working but nothing is cached. It always calls my server.

I tried many solutions, for example replacing $resource by $cacheFactory, but it's not working. I can't find the good way to do that.

Did I forget something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I find the problem:

I change my service like this:

```
mod.factory('Cities', ['$resource', function($resource) {return $resource('cities/', {}, {'query' : {method : 'GET', cache : true, isArray:true } });}]);
```

-> 'query' instead of 'list' and add isArray:true.